# I've installed GIT on Windows 7 32-bit and Git Bash is not opening

Tags: windows, git, git-bash, mintty

So I just started learning about GIT and installed GIT on my system. Everything is working: **Git GUI**, **Git CMD**, except **Git Bash**. It doesn't show any errors, it just doesn't open. I tried opening it as an admin, didn't worked. Or even opened through CMD, didn't worked either. Then I tried:

1. Creating a folder on desktop.
2. Right Click.
3. Selected "**Git Bash Here**" and it created a file named "**mintty.exe.stackdump**"

[The screenshot of file created.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3G5ju.png).

I didn't know what does it mean, or what can I do to make it Git Bash work. I hope someone can explain to me what happened or what can I do to solve this.

Comment: can u share the stack dump file.

Comment: The stack dump file is an error log, It would be best to include it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the below official community group from git and there you will find github link for updated version **2.28** for windows with fix of bug git-bash launch.

Download the **rco-32bit.exe** from there and it will work fine.
**2.28** version was announced on 10th July so no worries it will appear on site soon.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/git-for-windows